# Session-per-HttpRequest using Autofac. NHProf showing "multiple Session" warning when not accessing ISession through DependencyResolver

Tags: c#, session, nhibernate, autofac

I've successfully implemented Session-per-HttpRequest using Autofac.

I'm unhappy with my implementation because I am going through `DependencyResolver` and not relying on parameters provided by AutoFac. If I rely on the `ISession` parameter provided by AutoFac, then I receive a warning with NHProf indicating that there are multiple Sessions in use. If I go through `DependencyResolver`, the warning from NHProf disappears, but the usage feels incorrect to me.

I have followed the Autofac + MVC4.0 guidelines outlined here: https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MvcIntegration

I've also used this guide as a reference. It indicates that it should be possible to accept ISession as a constructor parameter: http://slynetblog.blogspot.com/2011/04/lightweight-nhibernate-and-aspnet-mvc.html

Here's how I build my Autofac container:

```
public class AutofacRegistrations
{
    public static void RegisterAndSetResolver()
    {
        var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

        containerBuilder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        //  Only generate one SessionFactory ever because it is expensive.
        containerBuilder.Register(x => new NHibernateConfiguration().Configure().BuildSessionFactory()).SingleInstance();

        //  Everything else wants an instance of Session per HTTP request, so indicate that:
        containerBuilder.Register(x => x.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession()).As<ISession>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
        containerBuilder.Register(x => LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType)).As<ILog>().InstancePerHttpRequest();

        containerBuilder.RegisterType<NHibernateDaoFactory>().As<IDaoFactory>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<StreamusManagerFactory>().As<IManagerFactory>().InstancePerHttpRequest();

        //  containerBuilder.RegisterModule adds all the required http modules to support per web request lifestyle and change default controller factory to the one that uses Autofac.
        containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new AutofacWebTypesModule());

        IContainer container = containerBuilder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
    }
}
```

And here is my base controller class. Note the commented out code which original accepted session as a parameter:

```
public abstract class StreamusController : Controller
{
    protected readonly ILog Logger;
    protected new readonly ISession Session;

    protected StreamusController(ILog logger, /*ISession session*/)
    {
        if (logger == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("logger");
        //if (session == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("session");

        Logger = logger;

        //  TODO: Is this different than passing ISession into Controller with AutoFac?
        Session = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ISession>();
        //Session = session;
    }

}
```

**I am experiencing different results with NHProf based on whether I work with ISession as a parameter or access it through DependencyResolver. Why?** My understanding is that these two means should be EXACTLY THE SAME!

For reference, here's my Lazy NHibernateConfiguration/ISessionFactory implementation. I don't think it's exceedingly relevant to the issue at hand:

```
public class NHibernateConfiguration
{
    public FluentConfiguration Configure()
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ConnectionString;

        FluentConfiguration fluentConfiguration = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(connectionString).ShowSql().FormatSql())
            .Mappings(cfg => cfg.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<UserMapping>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(ConfigureStreamusDataAccess);

        return fluentConfiguration;
    }

    private static void ConfigureStreamusDataAccess(Configuration configuration)
    {
        //  NHibernate.Context.WebSessionContext - analogous to ManagedWebSessionContext above, stores the current session in HttpContext. 
        //  You are responsible to bind and unbind an ISession instance with static methods of class CurrentSessionContext.
        configuration.SetProperty("current_session_context_class", "web");
        configuration.SetProperty("connection.isolation", "ReadUncommitted");
        configuration.SetProperty("default_schema", "[Streamus].[dbo]");
        configuration.SetProperty("generate_statistics", "true");
    }
}
```

Here are screenshots of NHProf indicating multiple sessions on my CreateMultiple action and another screenshot of it not indicating multiple sessions. The first screenshot uses ISession passed in as a parameter and the second screenshot uses DependencyResolver:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's happening, but you could write the registration like so:

```cs
containerBuilder.Register(x => {
    return x.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession(); //set breakpoint here
}).As<ISession>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

and the set a breakpoint on your OpenSession() call, then debug though your code and see what the call stack looks like each time it gets called.

Comment: That's a pretty good idea and also a really cool way of setting breakpoints which I didn't know of. I'll check it out, thanks.

Comment: If you figure something out, be sure to let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I tracked down the culprit. It wasn't immediately obvious.

I use AutoMapper to map DTO to Domain and back. This, apparently, was [bad practice](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/09/18/the-case-for-two-way-mapping-in-automapper/).

My logic looked something like:

- Application_Start
- AutofacRegistrations.RegisterAndSetResolver
- AutoMapper.SetMappings

Inside of SetMappings, I needed access to my DAO factory in order to map my DTO back to a Domain: [AutoMapper best practices - Should I be asking the DAO for information to fulfill mapping from DTO to domain object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138669/automapper-best-practices-should-i-be-asking-the-dao-for-information-to-fulfil)

In asked DependencyResolver for my DaoFactory. This is where the problem arose. I was asking for a DaoFactory before Autofac had a chance to create a session for my current request (since I wasn't IN a request yet.) This caused it to generate an ISession prematurely in order to be able to dish out a DaoFactory.

Refactoring my code such that each Domain object was responsible for re-mapping resolved the issue. Something like:

```
public static PlaylistItem Create(PlaylistItemDto playlistItemDto, IPlaylistManager playlistManager)
{
    PlaylistItem playlistItem = new PlaylistItem
        {
            Cid = playlistItemDto.Cid,
            Id = playlistItemDto.Id,
            Playlist = playlistManager.Get(playlistItemDto.PlaylistId),
            Sequence = playlistItemDto.Sequence,
            Title = playlistItemDto.Title,
            Video = Video.Create(playlistItemDto.Video)
        };

    return playlistItem;
}
```

where I've used IoC to give the IPlaylistManager to the PlaylistItem instead of getting access to it through DependencyResolver.