# NHibernate + ASP.NET Identity + Autofac cache issue

Tags: caching, nhibernate, asp.net-identity, autofac

I'm building a profile page with update form. After submitting the form with new data and several page refreshes I see sometime new and sometimes old data. It depends on thread handling current request. One thread contains new data and another one old. **NHibernate** is configured using **ThreadStaticSessionContext** and **NoCacheProvider**. In **Autofac** **UserStore**, **OwinContext.Authentication** and **UserManager** are configured as **InstancePerRequest**.

I tried to change **ThreadStaticSessionContext** to **CallSessionContext** and it started working normally. So the question is: why it works(**ThreadStaticSessionContext** is preferable for multithread apps) and what negative effects can it bring?

Thanks!

Comment: is this a windows or web app?

Comment: it's a web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ThreadStaticSessionContext is for long running processes such as windows services or windows apps.  For web applications you want to be implementing Session Per Request. This is what the WebSessionContext is for.

I actually don't use any of the contexts and just wire it up myself.  See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37887107/how-to-implement-session-per-request-pattern-in-asp-net-mvc-with-nhibernate/37887173#37887173) for an example.