# Updating entity 1:many nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am trying to solve problem with updating entity from form. I have typed view and form for entity Post and post has collection of pictures.

```
 public class Post : IEntity
    {
        public virtual int Id{ get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Každý článek musí mít titulek")]
        [MaxLength(250, ErrorMessage ="Nadpis může mít maximálně 250 znaků")]
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual string Annotation { get; set; }
        [AllowHtml]
        public virtual string Content { get; set; }
        public virtual User Author { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
        public virtual Rating Rating { get; set; }
        public virtual string PreviewImageName { get; set; }
        public virtual string ContentImageName { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<BlogImage>Gallery { get; set; }
    }
```

its mapped as one-to-many.

```
<bag name="Gallery" lazy="true" inverse="true"
                        batch-size="25" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
      <key column="post_id" />
      <one-to-many class="BlogImage" />
    </bag>
```

Now i am trying to add a picture from input to this collection. (Updating of all other columns is working just fine). So I take picture from input, create Picture object, persist it and then use Add(method) on Gallery collection on Post entity. Then I use update on post. But its not working. It throws exception: HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions. Anyone can see a problem? Thank you very much.

```
public class DaoBase<T> : IDaoBase<T> where T : class, IEntity
    {
        protected ISession session;

        protected DaoBase()
        {
            session = NHibernateHelper.Session;
        }

        public object Create(T entity)
        {
            object o;
            using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                o = session.Save(entity);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
            return o;
        }

        public void Delete(T entity)
        {
            using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                session.Delete(entity);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }

        public IList<T> GetAll()
        {
            return session.QueryOver<T>().List<T>();
        }

        public T GetById(int id)
        {
            return session.CreateCriteria<T>().Add(Restrictions.Eq("Id", id)).UniqueResult<T>();
        }

        public void Update(T entity)
        {
            using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                session.Update(entity);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And NHibernateHelper code as requested.

```
namespace DataAccess
{
    public class NHibernateHelper
    {
        private static ISessionFactory _factory;
        public static ISession Session
        {
            get
            {
                if (_factory == null)
                {
                    var cfg = new Configuration();
                    _factory = cfg.Configure(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "hibernate.cfg.xml"))
                        .BuildSessionFactory();
                }
                return _factory.OpenSession();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the code for NHibernateHelper.Session look like?  please add it to the question.  Also what type of application is this? windows? web?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. It is asp.net mvc web application. I added code you requested.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm going to guess that your create you you Picture object using 1 DAO and update the Post with a different DAO.  Your NHibernate helper is just handing out new Sessions every time a Session is asked for.  you want to share the same session per web request.

I would ditch the whole NHibernateHelper concept and just make the changes to you Global.asax.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37887107/how-to-implement-session-per-request-pattern-in-asp-net-mvc-with-nhibernate/37887173#37887173)

But what it boils down to is

1. create you SessionFactory in Application_Start, storing it in a static property of Global.asax
2. Create a Current Session Property that maps to an item in HttpContext.
3. Application_BeginRequest to open the session
4. Application_EndRequest to cleanup

I'd also look at modifying you DAO to not always create a new transaction.  You probably want all the db changes you make in a single request to be in a single transaction.

Here's code for the attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class TransactionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private ITransaction Transaction { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        Transaction = MvcApplication.CurrentSession.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (Transaction.IsActive)
        {
            if (filterContext.Exception == null)
            {
                Transaction.Commit();
            }
            else
            {
                Transaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I like to use a generic repository to show you how to use either a transaction started outside of the repo or create one if none exists.

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : EntityBase
{
    private readonly ISession _session;

    #region constructor

    public Repository(ISession session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Transact

    protected virtual TResult Transact<TResult>(Func<TResult> func)
    {
        if (_session.Transaction.IsActive)
            return func.Invoke();

        TResult result;
        using (var tx = _session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
        {
            result = func.Invoke();
            tx.Commit();
        }

        return result;
    }

    protected virtual void Transact(System.Action action)
    {
        Transact(() =>
        {
            action.Invoke();
            return false;
        });
    }

    #endregion

    #region IRepository<T> Members

    public void Save(T item)
    {
        Transact(() => _session.Save(item));
    }

    public Boolean Contains(T item)
    {
        if (item.Id == default(Guid))
            return false;

        return Transact(() => _session.Get<T>(item.Id)) != null;
    }

    public Int32 Count
    {
        get
        {
            return Transact(() => _session.Query<T>().Count());
        }
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        Transact(() => _session.Delete(item));
        return true;
    }

    public T Load(Guid id)
    {
        return Transact(() => _session.Load<T>(id));
    }

    public T Get(Guid id)
    {
        return Transact(() => _session.Get<T>(id));
    }

    public IQueryable<T> FindAll()
    {
        return Transact(() => _session.Query<T>());
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable<T> Members

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Transact(() => _session.Query<T>().Take(1000).GetEnumerator());
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Transact(() => GetEnumerator());
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you great answer. But I have a question, why this proble appears only with collections? I am using two daos for Author or Category and it is working just fine.

Comment: I think your questions explains that.  photo created and saved on session 1.  photo added to post (retrieved  by some other session).  post tries to save photo. boom! because of the separate sessions.  another things to look at is not adding a photo separately, but having an AddPhoto method on your post that creates and saves the Photo when the Post is saved.  One thing you shouldn't do in NHibernate is expose your collections.