# AdoTransaction - isolationlevel is null asp.net mvc 5 fluent nhibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a problem with save more than one items to database in c# asp.net with fluent nhibernate. I have :

```
   public static readonly ISessionFactory SessionFactory = DbContext.SessionFactory();
    public static readonly ISession Session = SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    public static readonly ITransaction Transaction = Session.BeginTransaction();

    public IEnumerable<Candidate> Candidates => Session.Query<Candidate>();

    public Candidate GetUser(int id)
    {
        return Session.Query<Candidate>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    }

    public void AddCandidate(Candidate candidate)
    {
        try
        {
            Session.Save(candidate);
            Transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
```

And the error is : IsolationLevel = '((NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction)Transaction).IsolationLevel' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

More information : can't access the deleted object

My Class DbContext:

```
 public static class DbContext
{
    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    static DbContext()
    {
        GetFactory();
    }
    public static void GetFactory()
    {
        var myEntities = new[]
        {
            typeof (ApplicationUser)
        };
        var configuration = Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("ConnectionString"))
                    .ShowSql())
                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()))
                .ExposeConfiguration(x =>
                {
                    x.SetProperty("", "");
                    x.AddDeserializedMapping(MappingHelper.GetIdentityMappings(myEntities), null);
                })
                .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema);

        _sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();

    }
    public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory()
    {
        return _sessionFactory;
    }

    public static ISession GetSession()
    {
        if (!CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(_sessionFactory))
            CurrentSessionContext.Bind(_sessionFactory.OpenSession());

        return _sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
    }
    public static ISession MakeSession()
    {
        return _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }
    //public static IUserStore<ApplicationUser, string> Users => new IdentityStore(MakeSession());

    private static void BuildSchema(Configuration config)
    {
        new SchemaUpdate(config)
            .Execute(true, true);
    }

}
```

Please, help!
Thanks!

Comment: IMHO, having the session and transaction as static fields is not a good design. Try and add the OpenSession() and BeginTransaction() calls to the AddCandidate() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SessionFactory` should be singleton and using it as static can be part of the solution. Objects from `ISession` and `ITransaction` should be created when necessary. Try change your code to something like this:

```
public static readonly ISessionFactory SessionFactory = DbContext.SessionFactory();

public Candidate GetUser(int id)
{
    Candidate candidate = null;
    using (var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
        candidate = Session.Query<Candidate>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    }
    return candidate;        
}

public void AddCandidate(Candidate candidate)
{
    using (var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
        using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                Session.Save(candidate);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch 
            {
                transaction.RollBack();
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Avoid to expose `Queryable` as your code is doing on the `Candidates` property.

There are some approaches to rightly implement the session management on an application and depending whant environment code is executed it can change.

I recommend you to see these posts:
http://benfoster.io/blog/yet-another-session-per-request-post

[How to implement session-per-request pattern in asp.net mvc with Nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37887107/how-to-implement-session-per-request-pattern-in-asp-net-mvc-with-nhibernate)

Comment: I am in the course of testing your code, it's work fine for now thanks a lot!